# Why we need compile PyQt before use it on Mac？

Tags: python, compiler, pyqt4

Why we need compile PyQt rather than simply using 'pip install' to put PyQt to my package repository? What happened during the compiling? Can I compiled PyQt once but allow many Macs through share folder to import it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyQt is a set of C++ bindings for the QT library so as C++ they either need to be compiled for your platform by you or someone else and linked with a specific build of QT. This is further complicated by the "dual licencing" of the QT library and some restrictions in the licence on redistribution *these may have been lifted now*.

Depending on the python version and platform you may be able to find wheel format downloads of PyQt that include the **LGPL** version of the QT library that pip can install.

If there are a group of you with the same platform and python/QT versions you should be able to build PyQt into a wheel, and install QT appropriately, for internal distribution provided your version and usage comply with any QT licence conditions